# Android GoogleMaps - set geojson feature not clickable

Tags: java, android, google-maps, onclicklistener, geojson

I have some `geojson` features shown on my map, representing events. When user click on feature, details are shown. It works fine, code:

```
layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(feature ->
{
  eventIndex= Integer.parseInt(feature.getProperty("eventIndex"));  
 /*Feature click logic*/
}
```

Also, I have added city boundary (it's actual **MultiPolygon** feature) and it has no '`eventIndex`' property, so I can easily ignore click events from it.

However, sometimes, when event feature is placed close to city boundary, there is boundary feature click event fired and not event feature click event. Of course, boundary feature click event is ignored in this case and it's not possible to show event details - click event contains only boundary feature data, not the one that user want to click.

Do you have any idea how set one, specific feature to be "not selectable" or "not clickable" on my map? City boundary should be used as completely static object, the same as labels on map.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

So, the only solution I found is to extract vertex coordinates from geojson and directly use  [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) to just draw static, not clickable line on map. Actually, some coding needed, but I see no any other way to stop big city boundary polygon shape from messing click events on my map. It must be static line (not even enclosed shape) and it can't be geojson feature.